# Nystrom approximation method in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to implement the Nystrom approximation method in Python. Assuming that i have already calculated the affinity matrixes A (between the selected samples) and B (between the rest samples and the selected samples), here is my code:

```
B_T = np.transpose(B)
d1 = np.sum(np.vstack((A, B_T)), 0)[np.newaxis]
d2 = np.sum(B, 0) + np.dot(np.sum(B_T, 0), np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(A), B))[np.newaxis]
dhat = np.sqrt(1./np.hstack((d1, d2))).T
A = np.dot(A, np.dot( dhat[0:subset_len], dhat[0:subset_len].T ) )
B1 = np.dot( dhat[0:subset_len], dhat[subset_len:].T)
B = B*B1
# here is the eigendecomposition
B_T = np.transpose(B)
Apseudo = np.sqrt(np.linalg.pinv(A))
BBT = np.dot(B,B_T)
W = np.vstack((A, B_T))
S = A + np.dot(Apseudo, np.dot(BBT, Apseudo) )
w,v = np.linalg.eigh(S)
ind = np.argsort(w)[::-1]
v = v[:, ind] # eigenvectors in decreasing order
w = w[ind] # eigenvalues in decreasing order
w = np.diag(w)
W = np.dot(W, Apseudo)
V1 = np.dot(W, np.dot(v, np.linalg.pinv(np.sqrt(w))))
m = 45 #embedding dimension
V = V1[:,:m]
# normalize eigenvectors to have unit length
for j in range(len(w)):
    V[:,j] = V[:,j]/np.sqrt(np.sum(V,0))
    V[:,j] = V[:,j]/np.linalg.norm(V[:,j])
```

When i execute the file, i get an error at the calculation of V1: **On entry to DLASCL parameter number  4 had an illegal value. Can please someone help me with the implementation and this error?

This is a brief explanation of the method for someone who is completely unaware of it.[Here is the Nystrom method](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~malik/papers/FBCM-nystrom.pdf)

Comment: I really cannot understand the negative vote. :/

Comment: Check whether you are not trying to take a root of a non-psd matrix. I think the method as reported in the paper has a bug allowing for this.

Comment: even if that is true, how can i compensate for that?

Comment: It's been ages since I've worked with this, but the problem is in the two-shot method. If you can only use the one-shot, you ought to be on the safe side.

Comment: Note: I'm not the negative vote, but this question seems unnecessarily hard to decipher. Actually showing the error message as output would help, as would showing the conditions under which you got the crash. Since the crash occurs when you calculate V1, I'd try splitting that line up into discrete operations to see if that helps - i.e. is there anything odd about v, w or W? can you take np.sqrt(w)? Once you do, can you get the pseudo-inverse? Is there anything odd about it? If things still seem reasonable, look at the various dot products... (HTH)

Comment: I have localized the problem and it occurs in the calculation of np.linalg.pinv(np.sqrt(w)))). The sort is calculated normally.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Can you please be more specific? And if you spot any errors on my implementation, please point them so as to fix it. Thnx

Comment: Check out your $S$. Does it have complex entries? If yes, that's the crux of the problem, because DLASCL expects its argument to be a *real* scalar, not a complex one.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg No, it does not have complex entries. Seems ok

Comment: So, any ideas anyone?